# Viewing my changelog in svn

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm using subversion locally on my machine. I have committed some changes to the repository. When I print svn status I get

```
?       binCharged
!       mem.xyz
?       binSge/.nfs00000000002c8aeb00000060
?       binSge/test.dat
?       binSge/propFile.dat
?       binSge/FTout.dat
?       binSge/mem
!       binSge/binSge/FTdev.dat
!       binSge/binSge/L.dat
!       binSge/binSge/Ltest.dat
!       binSge/binSge/prevProp.dat
!       binSge/binSge/mem.xyz
!       binSge/binSge/propFile.dat
!       binSge/binSge/FTout.dat
!       binSge/binSge/parOut.txt
!       binSge/binSge/file.txt
!       binSge/binSge/mem
```

Whis ok since binSge was not added to the repositories and it is used only for testing. When I print svn diff I get a blank line while [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.status) I understood that I am supposed to get some usefull output.

So how do I read my changelog and view the difference between the files?

I'm using scientific linux in commandline.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already committed your changes, `svn diff` will give you a blank output indeed.

If you know the revision number of your commit, you can get a change log
with the following command:

```
svn log -r 1234 -v
```

where, 1234 is your commit number.

Dropping the -r option will give you the entire log:

```
svn log -v | less
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I meant. Is there a way to watch the list of versions along with the commit line? Is there a way to compare two specific files?

Comment: If you mean compare two versions of the same file, but in different revisions, you can try:

`svn diff -r x1:x2 file_name`

where x1 and x2 are the two revisions that need to be compared